# React - Create Dashboard and read API Calls every few Minutes (Promise all) - Lagging

Tags: reactjs, dashboard

im currently creating a Website which uses API calls from Spring Boot and process them in a selfmade Dashboard site. The problem is, I've got many API's which need to be read and processed. In Context.js I'm reading all API's I have to process:

```
    loadDynamicData() {
    console.log("reading!")
    Promise.all([
        fetch("/api/v1/applications").then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
        fetch('/api/v1/dashboards').then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
        fetch('/api/v1/logs').then(function(response){ return response.json() }), 
        fetch('/api/v1/allLogs').then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
        fetch('/api/v1/connections').then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
        fetch(`/api/v1/errors`).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
        fetch(`/api/v1/users/${this.state.user}`).then(function(response){ return response.json() })
    ]).then(reponse =>{
        this.getApplications(reponse[0])
        this.setState({dashboards: reponse[1]}) 
        this.getLogs(reponse[2])
        this.getAllLogs(reponse[3]) 
        this.getConnections(reponse[4])
        this.getUserDashboardId(reponse[6])
        this.getErrors(reponse[5])

        this.getUserDashboard(this.state.userActiveDashboardId.userActiveDashboard)  
    })
}
```

loadingDynamicData is being called by componentDidMount every few Seconds:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.loadDynamicData(), 20000)
    this.checkRecentErrors();
}
```

This data is being processed in each of their methods and then made available in context.js to all other JSX Classes for further processing (like displaying lists, Graphs, etc...)

The reason why I need to get all those Informations every few seconds is, that all those API's are constantly updated and the Data constantly changes. Now the Problem is, that when the Data is being loaded (every 20000ms), the whole Website freezes and this is a huge problem, since you cant click on anything or do anything. This takes about 3 Seconds. Please, does anyone have a solution for this to make it better and avoid this loading/freezing times? Im farely new to React so any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever considered using React Developer Tools to see which components take that long to rerender?

Comment: Hello @FireFighter im 100% sure its allLogs, since that contains more than 10.000 Log entries. Im not sure how to improve that :/

Comment: You can use React.memo on components to make them not rerender if none of its props change.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll take a look into that!

Comment: After checking some issues, I actually found a more or less solution. So Instead of loading all logs every time, I load the big logs once, and a small snap of aprox 500 logs after that. This improved the issue by ALOT. There is still a small lag, and React.memo seems not to work at the small snap, as the props are constantly changing. So what I'm thinking of now, is outsourcing the snap from the other entries so it will not be loaded with the other ones and not slowing down all API calls